# Java - Defining a member that extends class A and implements interface B

Tags: java, object, generics, interface, anonymous-types

I have a variable that must meet two conditions, and I want to set them in the definition

I know that I can define either condition with an individual variable, like in any of these examples

```
private Class<? extends A> variable; //or
private A variable; //or
private Class<? extends B> variable; //or
private B variable;
```

But is there a way to have the variable meet both conditions?

I was hoping for something like this

```
private Class<? extends A implements B> variable;
```

But I can't find any way to do this without typecasting when I need to call it or storing multiple copies of it

Comment: What if you had an abstract class C that extends A and implements B? private Class<? extends C> variable;

Comment: Make your class generic, declare a type variable `T` with bounds of `A` and `B`, as `T extends A & B`, then declare a field of type `T`.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare type parameters that have multiple bounds, such as:

```
public static <T extends A & B> void test(Class<T> clazz)
```

But you cannot declare a variable that has multiple bounds:

```
private Class<? extends A & B> variable;  // doesn't work
```

You can create an `abstract` class `C` that extends `A` and implements `B`, so that only one bound is required.

```
abstract class C extends A implements B {}
```

Then:

```
private Class<? extends C> variable;
```

Comment: Here's the problem:

Class A is part of the Android framework;
Interface B is one that I've defined;

Class C is my own, which extends A;
Class E is my own, which needs to extend D (also part of Android), which extends A;

So the possible variables I can actually use will be instances of C or E, but their only common parent is A, which isn't one that I have control over.

Answer (score 1):

While Java does not directly support intersection types like `A&B`, such types do appear in type parameter bounds and capture conversions. We can express `A&B` with a layer of abstraction.

```
public class ValueAB<T extends A&B>
{
    public final T v;

    // constructor ...
}

public class ClassAB<T extends A&B>
{
    public final Class<T> clazz;

    // constructor ...
}
```

Instead of `A&B, Class<? extends A&B>`, we use wrappers `ValueAB, ClassAB`

```
    ClassAB<?> clazz = new ClassAB<>(Foo.class);   

    ValueAB<?> value = new ValueAB<>(clazz.c.newInstance());

    value.v.methodOfA();
    value.v.methodOfB();
```

This solution would require a wrapper for each combination of As and Bs.

---

Another solution is to use only `A` as type parameter bound;  `B` will be supplied by wildcard bound. This is probably better if you need to express multiple `A&B1, A&B2, ...` types at use site.

```
public class ValueA<T extends A>
{
    public final T v;
    ...
}


public class ClassA<T extends A>
{
    public final Class<T> c;
    ...
}

---

    ClassA<? extends B> clazz = new ClassA<>(Foo.class);

    ValueA<? extends B> value = new ValueA<>(clazz.c.newInstance());
```

If it's confusing how wildcard works in these cases, see my [article on wildcard](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html)

---

A 3rd solution is free of A or B at declaration site of wrappers; the use site provides A and B.

```
public class Value<T extends S, S>
{
    public final T v;
    ...
}


public class Clazz<T extends S, S>
{
    public final Class<T> c;
    ...
}

---

    Clazz<? extends A, B> clazz = new Clazz<>(Foo.class);

    Value<? extends A, B> value = new Value<>(clazz.c.newInstance());
```

This is however probably too confusing.