# Java multiple interfaces and reflection

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I have a class called X that implements multiple (e.g. 3) interfaces, call them A, B and C.

I create another interface AB that extends interface A and B.

How can I use reflection to create an instance of X that is assignable to interface AB?

I keep getting ClassCast exceptions with this code:

```
package test.messages;

public interface A
{
    void methodA();
}

package test.messages;

public interface B
{
    void methodB();
}

package test.messages;

public interface C
{
    void methodC();
}

package test.messages;

public interface AB extends A, B
{

}

package test.messages;

public class X implements A, B, C
{
    @Override
    public void methodC()
    {
        System.out.println("C");
    }

    @Override
    public void methodB()
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

    @Override
    public void methodA()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

Then in a completely different class:

```
AB api = (AB)Class.forName("test.messages.X").newInstance();

System.out.println(api);
```

Now when I try with just one interface, say A, it works fine.

Is there anyway to get it to work with the combined interface AB?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get an instance of `AB` from a class that doesn't implement `AB`.

Comment: You couldn't, though you could perhaps use a JDK proxy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32659085/2158288

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is *AND type* -- `A&B`. This is generally not supported in Java. However, we could create a wrapper class that contains a value that is both type A and type B. (It seems that every problem can be solved by a wrapper:)

```
public class AB<T extends A&B>
{
    public final T v;

    ... 
        v = (T)Class.forName("test.messages.X").newInstance();
}
```

Instead of using type `A&B`, we use `AB<?>` everywhere it's needed. We'll operate on its field `v`, which is both `A` and `B`.

```
void foo(AB<?> ab)
{
    ab.v.methodOfA();
    ab.v.methodOfB();
}
```

Or you could make `AB` a subtype of A and B too.

```
public class AB<T extends A&B> implements A, B
{
    public final T v;

    @Override // A
    public int methodOfA(){ return v.methodOfA(); }
```

See more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32659085/2158288

Answer (score 2):

The *is-a* relationship doesn't work that way. The fact that `AB` implements `A` and `B` and `X` implements `A` and `B` doesn't make `X` assignable to `AB`.

Even if you could think that `AB` is compatible with any type that implements `A` and `B` that's not the case as `AB` is a different type and the hierarchy tree in Java is fixed with the definition of the classes themselves.

Think about the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): if you add a method to `AB` then `X` is not a valid candidate anymore since it wouldn't contain the method declared in `AB`.

You would need a programming language that supports a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) to do it.

Comment: You did an excellent job of explaining why my approach didn't work when you mentioned what happens if you add a method to interface AB.  However, bayou.io better understood what I was trying to do and how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because in the inheritance tree X does not implement AB. 
If A,B,C are all interfaces a easy way to fix the problem is to say that X implements AB,C which that means it can be cast as A, as B, as C and as AB.

Comment: While this would work the real life scenario I am dealing with involves 10 interfaces.  So if I were to create a separate interface for every possible combination of those 10 I would have 1061 additional interfaces :)

Comment: That is inconvenient, to say the least. The answer is quite interesting although I must admit I don't fully understand how it helps. Don't you still need to create a whole bunch of interface combination wrappers?

Comment: I am the service provider exposing a single interface for each service function.  I am creating a user document for service consumers who might want to use more than one service at a time.  I merely want to show how to combine more than one interface in a single class for the consumer.  So I will not be creating combinations but consumers might...

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense :) 
@BigMac66 thanks for the explanation.