# Java bounded types as attributes

Tags: java, generics

Given classes `A` and `B`, with `a.methodA()` and `b.methodB()`, this works so far:

```
class C {
   ...
   public <X extends A & B> void setX(X x) { x.methodA(); x.methodB(); }
}
```

however, I would like to use that same x object later on as in

```
class C {
   X x; // <-- this does not compile
   public <X extends A & B> void setX(X x) { this.x = x; };
   public void Y() { x.methodA(); x.methodB(); }
}
```

Is there a way to declare an attribute of wildcard-type `X` without parametrizing the whole class with `X`? My current approach is

```
class C {
   A x; // (but would also work with B)
   public <X extends A & B> void setX(X x) { this.x = x; };
   public void Y() { x.methodA(); ((B)x).methodB(); }
}
```

Can I somehow avoid that `((B)x)` cast?

---

**Edit -** In my actual problem, `A` is a concrete class (`JComponent`), while `B` is an interface. I want to allow any `JComponent` that implements B to be passed in to method `setX()` -- if I created an

```
abstract class M extends JComponent implements B { ... }
```

I would no longer be able to call `setX(myJPanelThatImplementsB)` or `setX(myJLabelThatImplementsB)`, since they would need to derive from `M`.

Comment: Why do want to do this without parameterizing the class `class C<X extends A & B>`? That would be the obvious solution. Your solution requires a cast to `B` in method `Y`. In general you'll want to avoid casts.

Comment: You could have an interface `M` that extends `A` and `B`, and use that, instead of `A&B`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729711/java-multiple-interfaces-and-reflection/34729987#34729987

Comment: @thecoop class `A` is a concrete class, while class `B` is an interface. Editing to clarify.

Comment: @bayou.io see updated question. The link in your comment only applies to interface-only problems; and in my case I have an interface and a concrete class

Comment: @Jesper it would force me to "marry" with a specific A&B combo when the class C is instantiated - however, this obscures the fact that I expect to be able to call setX more than once with different A&B combos over the lifetime of an instance of C.

Comment: `class Wrapper<T extends JComponent & B>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you can not use type X for class fields if you do not use generics in class declaration.

Anyway, there's a naive solution with storing both links somewhere:

```
A xa;
B xb; 

public <X extends A & B> void setX(X x) { xa = x; xb = x };
```

Comment: It certainly works as advertised, although it does introduce some duplication. I will accept it unless anything better comes along.