# Composing generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics, types

I get a type-mismatch error in a situation I wouldn't expect.

```
public interface I {}

public abstract class C {}

public class A extends C implements I {}

public class B extends C implements I {}

public class Foo {

    public <T extends C & I> T getComposition(String selector) {
        switch (selector) {
            case "a": return new A(); // type-mismatch!
            case "b": return new B(); // type-mismatch!
        }
    }

}
```

Why `A`, which is both `C` and `I`, couldn't return as `T`?

Comment: If I call your method as `foo.<Hello>getComposition()`, this method is supposed to return an instance of `Hello`, but it returns an instance of `A`. A extends C & I. T also does. But that doesn't mean T and A are the same class.

Comment: I missed that! Thank you @JBNizet.

Comment: @JBNizet That explanation makes sense, but could you point to some further reading about that aspect of generics? And at least from my side, if that would be in an answer, I would upvote that ;-)

Comment: @GiovanniLovato, you can just cast your `new A()` to `T` and go further, but as JB Nizet said somewhere down below, it's not good to have such type of things in your code. Could you please provide more details so we can help you with your real case?

Comment: @GiovanniLovato The reason is that Test.class is of the type Class<C>. You cannot assign a reference of type Class<C> to a variable of type Class<T> as they are not the same thing.

Comment: Could you simply drop the generics and declare that `getComposition()` returns `C`? (or `I`). It doesn’t give you exactly the same, I know, but maybe you can live with it? If this is not enough, another thought is to define a subinterface of `I` that also includes all the (relevant) methods of `C` and use it as return type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32659085/2158288

Answer (score 4):

The notation `<T extends C & I>` means that `T` is a *type-parameter*. This means that when someone calls the function, they have to specify this type. The only restriction is that the type extends `C` and `I`. `A` is one such type, but I could create a new class that also extends `C` and `I`. Like this example:

```
class B extends C implements I {}

Foo foo = new Foo();
B b = foo.<B>getComposition();
```

If your example had compiled, this would result in an exception because `A` is not the same type as `B`.

If you really want to just return an `A`, you need to remove the generic parameter and make the return type `A` directly. Like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public A getComposition() {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to express "something" like this, using generics, but with that `new A()` in there?

Comment: @GhostCat I don't really understand why the method is generic in the first place. It shouldn't be, and its return type should just be A. I realize that the real case is probably more complex, but we don't know anything about it.

Comment: @JBNizet I've updated the example to be more similar to real case (which still remains just an example of course).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't really want to make your method generic. What you want to do is return a type that implements I, and also extends C. You shoud either make two methods (one returning I, and one returning C), or create an abstract class Foo that extends C and implements I, and meke sure that A and B both extend Foo.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct but just a part. A or B are T, that is absolutely correct. But T itself is not A or B at all. E.g. I have another class called D and D extends A. So, D is T also. If you say T is A, you also mean D is A. That is not correct at all since D is a subtype of A.